# Android Webview, formhash not working on some Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, hash, webview

I've been developing a web application on Android and iOS and working with a web view. Everything is working fine on the iPhone, but on Android it is not working on all devices and it is driving me crazy. On five Android devices it's working great, but on two devices it doesn't go further than the login page. However it does work on the mobile site (not app) in the browser.

The devices where the mobile app is not working on are HTC One (v4.3) and Acer Liquid Z3 (v4.2). Another device also HTC One (v4.3) it does work on and this makes the problem very difficult to understand and solve.

The first window when the application is opened is a simple login window. On the devices where it isn't working, it just reloads the page and the user can login again. The login information are checked with the details in a database. When it does work (or opened in the browser) it loads to a new page.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
private ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new DivumWebViewClient());

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.xxxx.com/index.php");

    loadingProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_title);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            loadingProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            if (newProgress == 100) {
                loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}

private class DivumWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

index.php

```
.....
<body class="blue-bg">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
} 
sec_session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; 

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
        exit;
    } else if(login($email, $password, $mysqli) == false){
        $error['error'] = "<p>Enter login details:</p>\n";
    }
} 
?>  
<div class="signin" style="margin-top: 0;">

    <div class="signin-body">

        <a href="index.php" title="Login" class="pull-right">
            <img src="../assets/images/logo.jpg" title="Login" alt="Login">
        </a>
        <br><h3>Login</h3>
        <?=$error['error']?>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" id="login-validatie" method="post"        name="login_form">                  
            <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Emailadres" name="email" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord" name="password" id="password">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <input type="submit" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" class="btn btn-med blue-bg pull-right" value="Inloggen">
            </div>

            <hr>          
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<script src="../assets/js/scripts.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if it a bug or something. It is strange it works on most devices, but not on some devices. It also works in the browser, which makes me think it has something to do with the web view in Android. I am at a dead end and appreciate every help. Thanks!

**update**
I've finally tracked where the problem lies and it has to do with form hashing. The password gives a different sha512 hash on some Android devices within the webview which makes it impossible to login. Don't know if it is a limitation of Android's web view on some devices, does anyone know how to solve this?

forms.js

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    form.appendChild(p);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}
```

functions.php

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM x WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        ?><script> var x; x = "<?php print($password); ?>"; console.log("Logging: password is " + x); </script><?

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                            "", 
                                                            $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                          $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When using on the iPhone app, Androids browser, desktop browsers or on some Android apps it gives a single sha5 hash: `c7d9a2def4f8d0f9c4b65d7522566ed33549b266174b2b12ae7f7b047e7efed2e92d18e552d1c812f073e794d16feb8ccf9df85399c475f24571472dece2d9b2`

but on some Android devices it gives one of the two hashes when using the same password for some weird reason:
`98488504186f9f69041c80217c311cfb4772f46319c945d3bc30c0c2db5650e675774bc6978749770b598e70d4553ec0391e7d3ec0b56d51eef51eeadbb7e10e`

`a3e08c365ef82d4256d8e58fd63b53d63d50b6b3cac3cdaba395cc73289e5f955491f11f06408c2c6e6ae531d69ddb10f234ecef0cf375d9782abea27909c9ef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had this problem before, my webview would fail to open a url in the current window, and after a short time android os would pick up the url and try to open it in a browser. I have a very similar implementation.

This straight from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is what your looking for I believe:

`Creating and setting a WebViewClient subclass. It will be called when things happen that impact the rendering of the content, eg, errors or form submissions. You can also intercept URL loading here (via shouldOverrideUrlLoading()).`

The `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` Method tells the webview that I want to handle the Load Action on all urls submitted through this WebView

You can see how i handled this at [My Github Project](https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/BioMedArticles/blob/master/src/com/divshark/genericjsonparserdemo/fragments/WebViewFragment.java) starting at line 226 , Where i added an additional innerclass which extends the WebViewClient class.

**Side Notes**

This works in my application on most devices I support. But you may also want to make sure that you URL is fully qualified. I have found that when any url i am using doesn't have

**http://**

on the front of it, the WebView will fail to load the URL even with the Additional WebViewClient. Object and shouldOverrideUrlLoading() call.

Have you tried the following after a failed load ? See if this will refresh the state of the webview , and once it does, make a new request to the URL you really want.

WebView.loadUrl("about:blank")

Have you tried not using javascript in the WebView ?

I have heard that this can be a potential security hole, and that it has a decent impact on the WebView rendering a webpage.

Good Luck!

**UPDATE**

It looks like your problem is not with your webview but your php script correct?

Try using this from Java When creating a password, or checking if the user password is right :

```
String password = "123456"; 
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); 
md.update(password.getBytes()); 
byte byteData[] = md.digest();
```

You really only need to do this on one side either your application or your server scripts. I would choose from the application side, since this way you send hashed passwords over the network instead of plain text.

Comment: Thanks, but I already created a additional webviewclient named DivumWebViewClient as can be seen in the code. I also checked the http:// and that also can't be the problem. After some hours I think I've finally tracked the problem. It has to do with form hashing and encryption. Some Android devices give different sha hashing and that makes it not possible to login. Still don't know how to solve it, but finding the problem helps a lot. :)

Comment: You could try changing your hashing functions to one compatible with both Java and php, so you can pass the encrypted password on the network and receive it in your php scripts. I believe that sha-256 is will work, or sha-1 but thats less secure                                    `String password = "123456";
 
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
 
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();`

Comment: Yes I've used a different hashing function and it works now on all devices. I think it's some kind of weird bug in Android webview. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using a different hashing function and it works now on all devices. I think it's some kind of weird bug in Android webview.